# Turtlebot Odometry Calibration (with and without IMU) Observations/Questions

Tags: navigation, odometry, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After adding the Razor 9DOF IMU from Sparkfun, the resulting Odometry actually seems to have gotten worse as shown in the two videos below:

1. Wheels-only Odometry, IMU disabled,
   analog Gyro disabled:
   https://youtu.be/ibY_HCBGm6U
2. Wheels + IMU, analog Gyro disabled:
   https://youtu.be/mPiKbtP5szM

Both show the robot's position with respect to the `/odom` frame as calculated by `robot_pose_ekf`. If the odometry was perfect (i.e. no error) then the position of the walls as seen by the Neato XV-11 LIDAR would remain in the same place as the robot is moved around.

The wheels-only odometry has a long-term drift as the TurtleBot is rotated continuously (via joystick telop). In the short term, though, it is pretty accurate and can probably be improved further by fine tuning the scaling parameters.

The wheel+IMU odometric position gyrates pretty significantly per turn but there is no long term drift.

When localizing with AMCL, adding the IMU will likely produce worse results because Localization can compensate for long term odometric drift but the short term gyrations will throw it off.

I did calibrate the IMU as described in the wiki page, including the Magnetometer (Section 7.1.3). The `calibration_magn_use_extended` parameter is set to `true`.

I'm looking for suggestions on how the improve the results of the wheels+IMU odometry. Thanks.

Also, here's the Matlab Analysis of the Magnetometer configuration data. I'm not sure how this is supposed to be interpreted. Please let me know if something's wrong.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228750/turtlebot-odometry-calibration-(with-and-without-imu)-observations/questions/) by [sakumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22747/sakumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the problem *was* in the Mag calibration.  I redid the calibration procedure *while the IMU was mounted on the Turtlebot*. I picked up the Turtlebot and moved it around in all directions as in the instructions. The "Ellipsoid Center" values came out significantly different:

Standalone Calibration Results:

```
const float magn_ellipsoid_center[3] = {138.402, -65.8241, -12.1968};
const float magn_ellipsoid_transform[3][3] = {{0.847013, -0.00538074, 0.00712010}, {-0.00538074, 0.865221, 0.00961725}, {0.00712010, 0.00961725, 0.999017}}
```

Results when mounted on the Turtlebot:

```
const float magn_ellipsoid_center[3] = {135.215, 4.24598, 5.24594};
const float magn_ellipsoid_transform[3][3] = {{0.820361, -0.0188837, 0.0166510}, {-0.0188837, 0.831140, 0.0388830}, {0.0166510, 0.0388830, 0.990194}};
```

Notice the changes in the Y and Z values of the Ellipsoid Center.

After this, the combined results of Wheels + IMU odometry were much better than wheels-only.

Other things to note:

- Experiment with positioning the IMU
  to minimize interference.
- Verify the    ellipsoid center values
  -- the IMU    node prints out the values on startup    -- at least twice they were not correct (missing one digit). Not    sure  why that    happened.
- The    instructions    say to modify the       Arduino firmware    with   these       values. I found that it  was       sufficient to change the   parameters in the launch file (my_razor.yaml) -- no need to modify the firmware.

Edited to add: I had noted above that the `ellipsoid_center` or `ellipsoid_transform` values were getting corrupted on the readback from the IMU (after calibration configuration was sent to the IMU). Suspecting that it may be a serial line buffer overflow type of problem I added a few `rospy.sleep(1)` while writing these values from `imu_node.py`. Happy to report that that seems to have done the trick. The read-back values are no longer corrupted. Most definitely a hack, and perhaps specific to my particular IMU but it works!

---

Originally posted by [sakumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22747/sakumar/) with karma: 26 on 2016-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0